# characteristic functions of A and B. proofs

Tags: real-analysis

friends I want to know if I have solved it correctly, otherwise I ask you to help me with the correct form. How is part d) and e)?

Let $X$ be a set, $A$ and $B$ subsets of $X$. If $\chi_A$  and $\chi_B$ are the characteristic functions of $A$ and $B$, respectively, show that:

a) $\chi_{A\cup B}=\chi_A+\chi_B-\chi_A\cdot\chi_B$.

b) $\chi_{A\cap B}=\chi_A\cdot\chi_B$.

c) $\chi_{A^\complement}=1-\chi_A$.

d) $\chi_{A-B}=\chi_A(1-\chi_B)$.

e) $\chi_{A\Delta B}=\lvert\chi_A-\chi_B\rvert$.

a) if $ x\in{} A\cup{}B$ , then $ \chi_ {A\cup{}B} \ (x) = x$
According to the different cases we have:
$x\in{}A \cup{}B \Rightarrow{} \chi_A \ (x)+ \chi_B \ (x) - \chi_A \ (x) . \chi_B \ (x) =
x \in{}A$ and $x\not\in B \Longrightarrow{} \chi_A \ (x) + \chi_B \ (x) - \chi_A \ (x) . \chi_B(x)
x\not\in A$ and $x \in{}B \Rightarrow{} \chi_A \ (x) + \chi_B \ (x) - \chi_A \ (x) . \chi_B \ (x)$
If $x \not\in A\cup{}B$, then
$\chi_{A \cup{} B} \ (x) = 0 $ since $ x\not\in A $ and $x\not\in B$
$\chi_{A} \ (x)+ \chi_B \ (x) - \chi_A \ (x) . \chi_B \ (x) = 0+0 - 0 * 0$
So
$\supset{}x \in{} \chi$ is verified
$\chi_{A \cup B} \ (x) = \chi_A \ (x) + \chi_B \ (x)-\chi_A \ (x) * \chi_B \ (x) $
Which implies that:
$\chi_{A \cup{} B} = \chi_A + \chi_B - \chi_A * \chi_B$

b)$ x \in{}A\cap{}B \Rightarrow{} x \in{} A $ and $x \in{}B \Longrightarrow{} \chi_{A \cap B} \ (x) =1.$
Namely; if $x \in{} A \cap{}B$ then $\chi_{A \cap B} \ (x) = \chi_A \ (x) \chi_B \ (x)$
On the other hand:
$x\not\in A \cap B \rightarrow{} x\not\in A $or $X \not\in B \rightarrow{} \chi_{A \cap B} \ (x) = 0$
Therefore if $x \not\in A \cap B,$ then also $\chi_{A \cap B} \ (x)= \chi_A \ (x) \chi_B \ (x)$
We conclude that :
$\chi_{A \cap B} = \chi_A . \chi_B$

c)$ \chi_{A^c} = 1 - \chi_A$
We have that $x \in{} A \rightarrow{} x \not\in A^c \rightarrow{} \chi_A \ (x) =1$ and $ \chi_A \ (x) = 0$
$x \not\in A \rightarrow{} x \in{}A^c \rightarrow{} \chi_A \ (x) =0 $ and $\chi_{A^c} \ (x) = 1$
Since $\chi_{A^c} \ (x) =1 - \chi_A \ (x)$  for all $ x \in X $ we conclude that $\chi_{A^c} =1 - \chi_A$

Comment: I think you might have the right idea, but that jumbled mess is too unclear.  Please work on your presentation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems correct, but a bit long. I would do it differently. I would change the order of the proof, to be able to use the results from other points.

First observe that the both sides of the equalities (b) and (c) can be only $0$ or $1$. Therefore it sufficies to show that they attain value $1$ for the same set of  arguments.

b) $\chi_A(x)\cdot\chi_B(x)=1\iff \chi_A(x)=1$ and $\chi_B(x)=1 \iff  x\in A$
and  $x\in B \iff x\in A\cap B\iff \chi_{A\cap B}(x)=1$.

c) $1-\chi_A(x)=1\iff \chi_A(x)=0\iff x\notin A\iff x\in A^c\iff \chi_{A^c}(x)=1$.

d) $A\setminus B = A\cap B^c$, so from (b) and (c) we have $\chi_{A\setminus B} = \chi_A\cdot \chi_{B^c}=\chi_A\cdot (1-\chi_B)$.

a) $\chi_{A\cup B}=\chi_{(A^c\cap B^c)^c}=1-\chi_{A^c\cap B^c} = 1-\chi_{A^c}\cdot \chi_{B^c}=1-(1-\chi_A)\cdot(1-\chi_B)=\mathrm{rhs}$

In the special case if $A\cap B=\emptyset$ we get $\chi_{A\cup B}=\chi_{A}+\chi_{B}$

e) Since $A\Delta B=A\setminus B\cup B\setminus A$ (disjoint sum) then
$$\chi_{A\Delta B}=\chi_{A\setminus B}+\chi_{B\setminus A} = \chi_A(1-\chi_B)+\chi_B(1-\chi_A)=\chi_A-2\chi_A\cdot\chi_B+\chi_B.\tag{*}$$ Now observe that $\chi_C=\chi_C^2$. Then
from (*) we get
$$\chi_{A\Delta B}^2=\chi_{A\Delta B}= (\chi_A-\chi_B)^2.
$$
Therefore $\chi_{A\Delta B} = |\chi_A-\chi_B|$.

Comment: Thank you very much, is part a) correct? any other way to demonstrate in a much simpler way?